# Destructure a tuple into function parameters in swift

Tags: swift

Consider a basic `swift` function to separate the components of a fully qualified path:

```
public static func splitPath(_ path: String)  -> 
      (directory: String,
       filenameOnly: String, 
       ext: String) {
  let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
  return (url.deletingLastPathComponent().path, 
          url.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent, url.pathExtension)
}
```

Now consider a method `readFile` that takes the same number and types of parameters:

```
  public static func readFile(_ subDir: String, 
      _ fname: String = "", 
      _ ext: String = "") throws -> String { ... }
```

How can that `readFile` method be invoked directly given the returned tuple of `splitPath()` ?

```
    let fcontents = try readFile(splitPath(path))
```

In other languages this is performed via `splat` of variadic parameters.

Comment: I see it has been discussed at forums.swift.org but with no result so far, maybe [this page](https://gist.github.com/callionica/43f79dd0a9b145746d72e8a8a62c2820) could be helpful. With some tweaking you could write `let fcontents = splat(splitPath(path), readFile)`

Comment: Unless you have some other constraints going on, I wouldn't suggest making a function that takes separate params like that. All this seems like it should be a struct, or really, just a `Foundation.URL`.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica  The first line is converting to a `URL` . The `iOS` naming conventions for `URL`'s are involved and should not be spread everywhere within every layer of the App.  It is for this purpose that paths are specified in my app that are  sandbox-relative. Conversion to absolute paths is in one place.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson  That method is hardcoded to three arguments:I'd have to make a separate one for each different parameter lists length. Not impossible but also not the first choice

Comment: @javadba Sure, if you feel the need to abstract yourself from `URL`, then make a struct that doesn't it. Don't just pass around free-form strings like this.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica  I see where you are coming from. What about the original question - i.e. swift equivalent of splat / destructuring?

Comment: @javadba Nope, there isn't an operator for that, I'm afraid. Sometimes it's a bummer, but generally tuples are meant for simple returns, like for https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/3128848-insert

Answer (score 0):

This feature called `implicit` `tuple` `splat` removed in `swift 3`.If you want to know more details you can find it [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0029-remove-implicit-tuple-splat.md)

But you can use tuple as function parameter like this

```
public  func readFile( _ tuple: (directory:String, filenameOnly:String , ext:String )) throws -> String { //... }
```

Comment: Interesting.. i'm not going to read that presently since it would likely make me unhappy.. afa the suggestion: would that not lose the naming of the path/name/ext?  It does not really feel like an answer but just a complete redo of the api due to the apparent language omission.

Comment: does it helps you ?

Comment: Not really since I was already aware of the use of tuples but was interested in `splat` to spread them out .